# npm install frozen when installing dependencies for react on raspberry pi

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, raspberry-pi

I have a react project hosted on my raspberry pi that has been working well for a while. I made some changes on my pc and then pulled those changes on the raspberry pi, and did npm run build. This didn't work and froze the terminal even though it has worked many times previously. I then removed the node modules folder and tried to do npm install, which took a long time and then just froze. It usually stops at lines similar to this ⸨#####⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⸩ ⠴ idealTree:tsutils: http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@swc%2fcore 169561ms (cache miss)

I've even left it over night and the SSH terminal has just disconnected me as it takes so long. I've made new react projects and tried to do npm install and it has likewise frozen. However, I've done npm install for an express js project and it worked fine.

Ive tried: reinstalling npm and node, doing this "npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global" , deleting package-lock.json, checking that I have enough disk space (I have plenty) and I have cleaned the npm cache.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: note the raspberry pi is running ubuntu server

Comment: I have the same issue right now. Have you found the solution?